# Reading a pdf from phone and storing it in a string in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, pdf

I am working on an android app that requires browsing a pdf from phone and then storing it's content into a String. I have the following code:

```
 //src= location of the pdf file obtained from while browsing pdf from the phone (eg:"/sdcard/bluetooth/My_pdf.pdf")
        public void convertPDFToText(String src) {
        try {
               //create pdf reader
               PdfReader pr = new PdfReader(src);    

              //get the number of pages in the document
               int pNum = pr.getNumberOfPages();

            //extract text from each page and write it to the output text file
            for (int page = 1; page <= pNum; page++) {

            //text is the required String (initialized as "" )
            text = text + PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pr, page);
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
```

When I run this code separately in a java file, it runs perfectly fine (changing the src input according to the location of the pdf in the system), but when I run the same code in android studio, it gives me an exception saying:

```
java.io.IOException: /sdcard/bluetooth/My_pdf.pdf not found as file or resource.
at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createByReadingToMemory(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:263)
at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:173)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:223)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:207)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
at com.example.prachisingh.summer.DisplayActivity.convertPDFToText(DisplayActivity.java:112)
at com.example.prachisingh.summer.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) resource.I need help figuring out the cause of this error.
```

Here is my AndroidMAnifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.Computer.app_name">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Did you add the permissions to write to external storage? Please show us your `Manifest.xml` file.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Try calling `file.exists()` to make sure.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla I had already given permissions to read and write the external storage. I have also added my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: @TychoTheTaco I checked if the file exists on the location I am trying to input in my convertPDFToText function, and it gives me **true** .But I still get the same error.

Comment: I am in desperate need of knowing your exact **src** path. Try observing the path again if it's correct and well formatted.

Comment: The example I gave is my exact src path. I have a pdf named My_pdf in bluetooth folder in sd card. Also I added a code to open My_pdf using the very same src path, and it works fine. 
_File file = new File(src) ;
 if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file) ;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) ;
            i.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf") ;
            startActivity(i);_

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path directory in a more "formal and right" way instead of hardcoding the path.

Comment: @AownRaza I am not hardcoding the path. I am browsing pdf from phone and then getting it's path, using the code given on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302143/browse-and-upload-pdf-or-word-file-in-android/37309153#37309153?newreg=96d2efbe54044a1b840785c91f4df238). And the path is perfectly correct as I am able to view my pdf from the path obtained in Reader as well. Just that when I call convertPDFToText function on the same path, it gives me the above mentioned error.

Comment: The [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302143/browse-and-upload-pdf-or-word-file-in-android/37309153#37309153?newreg=96d2efbe54044a1b840785c91f4df238) you provided has no accepted answer. Try using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) library. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299839/how-to-read-pdf-in-my-android-application) SO post may also be helpful for you.

Comment: I modified the code from the link I provided above. The link you provided gives solution to _displaying_ a pdf, while I want to read the text from the pdf and store it in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your **AndroidManifest.xml**.
Also if your target SDK is 23 or higher you must request for this permission while the app is running. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Example implementation may look like this:

1. Create helper class for requesting permissions

   ```
   public class PermissionChecker {

       private final Activity activity;
       private final View layout;
       private final int requestCode;
       private final String permission;
       private final String description;

       public PermissionChecker(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull View layout,
                        int requestCode,
                        @NonNull String permission,
                        @NonNull String description) {
           this.activity = activity;
           this.layout = layout;

           this.requestCode = requestCode;
           this.permission = permission;
           this.description = description;
       }

       public void requestPermission() {
           if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
               // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
               // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
               // Display a SnackBar with a button to request the missing permission.
               Snackbar.make(layout, description, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       requestPermission(activity, permission, requestCode);
                   }
               }).show();
           } else {
               // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
               requestPermission(activity, permission, requestCode);
           }
       }

       public boolean checkPermission() {
           return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
       }

       public boolean onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, int[] grantResults) {
           return requestCode == this.requestCode
               && ((grantResults.length > 0)
               && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
       }

       private void requestPermission(Activity activityContext, String permission, int requestCode) {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activityContext, new String[] { permission }, requestCode);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your Activity should implement **OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback**

   ```
   implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback
   ```
3. Init PermissionChecker for external storage permission.

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // ...

       View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

       readExternalStoragePermissionChecker = new PermissionChecker(this, rootView,
           PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           "Read external storage access is required to read pdfs from sdcard."
           );

       if (readExternalStoragePermissionChecker.checkPermission()) {
           convertPDFToText(path);
       }
       else {
           readExternalStoragePermissionChecker.requestPermission();
       }

       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Override **onRequestPermissionsResult** method in your Activity.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       if (readExternalStoragePermissionChecker.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, grantResults)) {
           convertPDFToText(path);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @coder_91 Can you make one more test: **File file = new File(src); if (!file.canRead()){ throw new Exception("Read permission error"); }**

Comment: On trying that, it gives me the exception saying "Read permission error". So, the file cannot be read. How can I sort that?

Comment: What version of Android and what model of phone do you have?

Comment: I am using MotoG(3rd generation) of Android version 6.0.1.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer for Android 6 and sdk 23. It should work

Comment: Thank you, but when I call the constructor of PermissionChecker as `readExternalStoragePermissionChecker = new PermissionChecker(this, rootView,PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,"Read external storage access is required to read pdfs from sdcard.")` I get this error saying: PermissionChecker() has private access in android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker. Also I cannot access it's functions. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: @coder_91 You're importing wrong **PermissionChecker** class (**android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker**) - You should import PermissionChecker included in the answer code.